# Running SQL Stored Procedure in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am not familiar with PHP but am trying to figure out why this isn't working.  I trying to run an SQL stored procedure which takes in some parameters via php.  This code is supposed to add an extra line in the form for user data entry based on the criteria.  When I run the stored procedure directly in SQL Server Management Studio it works fine and adds the row to the back end table and reflects the row in the front-end form, but when try to add the row in front-end with the underlying code, I get no error and nothing updates.

I am not familiar with PHP but am trying to learn and figure out why this isn't working.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the underlying PHP code.

```
<?PHP include 'Connections/PromAPPS01Connection.php'; ?>
<?php
session_start();
$sUserid = "9999";
if(isset($_SESSION['sUserID'])){
    $sUserid = $_SESSION['sUserID'];
    //echo "Yes";
}
else{
    /* Redirect browser */
    header("Location: LoginSession.php");
    /* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
    exit;
    //echo "No";
}

$sPostPropertyId = $_POST["Props"];
$sPostGroupId = $_POST["AcctGroup"];
$sRecordStart = $_POST["RS"];
$sPostAcct = $_POST["Acct"];
$sPostYear = $_POST["Year"];
$sBudgetID = $_POST["BudgetID"];
$sPostRowCount = $_POST["AcctCount"];
$sSubmitType = $_POST["SubmitType"];
$sView = $_POST["View"];
$sAddLineAcct = $_POST["NewLineAcct"];
$sAddLineProp = $_POST["NewLineProp"];
$sAddLineYear = $_POST["NewLineYear"];
$sPropertyNumber = $_POST["PropertyNumber"];
$sType = $_POST["Type"];
$sDept = $_POST["Dept"];
$sComments = $_POST["Comments"];
$sAddType = $_POST["AddType"];

$sqlNewLine = "Exec Budgeting.procAddNewLines '". $sPostPropertyId ."', '". $sPropertyNumber ."', '". $sAddLineAcct ."', '". $sAddType ."','". $sType ."', '". $sAddLineYear ."', '". $sPostYear ."', '". $sComments ."', '". $sUserid ."','". $sDept ."' ";
//echo "<br>";
//echo $sAddType ." & ". $sAddLineYear . " &". $sPostYear;

if ($sRecordStart == ""){ 
    $sRecordStart = 0;
}

$iNextRS = $sRecordStart;

$navigateLocation = "PlanSheetProperty.php";

//echo "<br>";
//  echo $sqlNewLine;
    // Executing the sql update code
        //conn.Execute sql_New_Line
    //#####################################################################
    $stmtNewLine = sqlsrv_prepare($dbLink, $sqlNewLine);

    sqlsrv_execute($stmtNewLine);
            //#################################

?> 
<html>
<head>
<Link Rel="Stylesheet" href="RenewStyle.css" type="text/css">
    <title>The Budget Machine</title>
</head>
<!--body-->
<body onLoad="document.AcctUpdate.submit();">
<?PHP include 'Top.php'; ?>

<table width="100%" bordercolor="#003366" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr class="Title1">
        <td valign="bottom">&nbsp;

        </td>
        <td colspan="5" rowspan="2" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;

        </td>
        <td colspan="13" align="right" valign="bottom" nowrap>&nbsp;

        </td>
        <td align="right" valign="bottom" nowrap>&nbsp;

        </td>
        <td align="right" valign="bottom" nowrap>&nbsp;

        </td>
        <td align="right" valign="bottom" nowrap>
        <!--input type="Button" value="< Back to Properties" onClick="document.location='PropertyList.asp'"-->
        </td>
        <td valign="bottom">&nbsp;

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Title1">
        <td valign="bottom">&nbsp;

        </td>
        <td colspan="5" rowspan="2" valign="middle" nowrap>&nbsp;

        </td>
        <td colspan="13" align="left" valign="bottom" nowrap>
        Saving data...<br>
        Please be patient
        </td>
        <td align="right" valign="bottom" nowrap>&nbsp;

        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $navigateLocation ?>" name="AcctUpdate" id="AcctUpdate" />        
        <input type="hidden" name="RS" id="RS" value="<?PHP echo $iNextRS ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="Props" id="Props" value="<?PHP echo $sPostPropertyId ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="AcctGroup" id="AcctGroup" value="<?PHP echo $sPostGroupId ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="GLAcct" id="GLAcct" value="<?php echo $sAddLineAcct ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="AcctCount" id="AcctCount" value="<?PHP echo $sPostRowCount ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="BudgetID" id="BudgetID" value="<?PHP echo $sBudgetID ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="NewLineAcct" id="NewLineAcct" value="<?php echo $sPostAddLineAcct ?>">        
        <input type="hidden" name="PropertyNumber" id="PropertyNumber" value="<?php echo $sPostPropertyNumber ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="SubmitType" id="SubmitType" value="<?php echo $sSubmitType ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="View" id="View" value="<?php echo $sView ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="NewLineProp" id="NewLineProp" value="<?php echo $sPostAddLineProp ?>">
        </form>
        </td>
        <td align="right" valign="bottom" nowrap>&nbsp;

        </td>
        <td align="right" valign="bottom" nowrap>&nbsp;

        </td>
        <td align="right" valign="bottom" nowrap>
        </td>
        <td valign="bottom">&nbsp;

        </td>
    </tr>
     </table>
</td></tr></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the stored procedure:

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER Procedure AddNewLines
(
    @PropertyID numeric (10,0) = NULL,
    @PropertyNumber varchar (30) = NULL,
    @GLAccountNumber varchar (10) = NULL,
    @InsertType varchar (10) = NULL,
    @LineAssoc varchar (10) = NULL, 
    @ClickYear varchar (30) = NULL,
    @Year varchar (30) = NULL,
    @Comments varchar (800) = NULL,
    @User int = NULL,
    @DeptCode varchar (10) = NULL
) AS




IF @InsertType = 'Single'
    BEGIN
    IF @LineAssoc = 'Project'
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO BudDat(PropertyID, 
            PropertyNumber, 
            GLAccountNumber, 
            Project, 
            [Year], 
            BudgetID, 
            Comments, 
            LastChangedDate, 
            LastChangedBy) 
            VALUES (@PropertyID, 
            @PropertyNumber, 
            @GLAccountNumber, 
            'Y', 
            @ClickYear, 
            '', 
            @Comments, 
            getDate(), 
            @User)
        END



    IF @LineAssoc = 'None'
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO BudDat(PropertyID, 
            PropertyNumber, 
            GLAccountNumber, 
            DeptCode, 
            [Year], 
            BudgetID, 
            Comments, 
            LastChangedDate, 
            LastChangedBy) 
            VALUES (@PropertyID, 
            @PropertyNumber, 
            @GLAccountNumber, 
            @DeptCode,
            @ClickYear, 
            '', 
            @Comments, 
            getDate(), 
            @User)
        END
    END

IF @InsertType = 'Multiple'
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @YearCount int
    Select @YearCount = 0
    IF @LineAssoc = 'Project'
        BEGIN
        WHILE (@YearCount < 5)
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO BudDat(PropertyID, 
                PropertyNumber, 
                GLAccountNumber, 
                Project, 
                [Year], 
                BudgetID, 
                Comments, 
                LastChangedDate, 
                LastChangedBy) 
                VALUES (@PropertyID, 
                @PropertyNumber, 
                @GLAccountNumber, 
                'Y', 
                @Year, 
                '', 
                @Comments, 
                getDate(), 
                @User)
            Select @YearCount = @YearCount+1
            Select @Year = @Year+1
            END
        END



    IF @LineAssoc = 'None'
        BEGIN
        WHILE (@YearCount < 5)
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO BudDat(PropertyID, 
                PropertyNumber, 
                GLAccountNumber, 
                DeptCode, 
                [Year], 
                BudgetID, 
                Comments, 
                LastChangedDate, 
                LastChangedBy) 
                VALUES (@PropertyID, 
                @PropertyNumber, 
                @GLAccountNumber, 
                @DeptCode,
                @Year, 
                '', 
                @Comments, 
                getDate(), 
                @User)
            Select @YearCount = @YearCount+1
            Select @Year = @Year+1
            END
        END
    END
```

Comment: As I said I don't really know much about PHP but a procedure doesn't do something different when it is called from somewhere else. I don't know how to properly call a stored procedure from PHP but it looks to me like you are executing a pass through query. This is vulnerable to sql injection. You should instead parameterize your procedure call.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about PHP but you could greatly simplify that stored proc. No need for loops and that sort of thing for this. This should do the same thing.

```
ALTER Procedure AddNewLines
(
    @PropertyID numeric (10,0) = NULL,
    @PropertyNumber varchar (30) = NULL,
    @GLAccountNumber varchar (10) = NULL,
    @InsertType varchar (10) = NULL,
    @LineAssoc varchar (10) = NULL, 
    @ClickYear varchar (30) = NULL,
    @Year varchar (30) = NULL,
    @Comments varchar (800) = NULL,
    @User int = NULL,
    @DeptCode varchar (10) = NULL
) AS

    IF @LineAssoc = 'Project'
        INSERT INTO BudDat(PropertyID, 
            PropertyNumber, 
            GLAccountNumber, 
            Project, 
            [Year], 
            BudgetID, 
            Comments, 
            LastChangedDate, 
            LastChangedBy) 
            select @PropertyID, 
            @PropertyNumber, 
            @GLAccountNumber, 
            'Y', 
            @ClickYear, 
            '', 
            @Comments, 
            getDate(), 
            @User
            from (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) as Numbers(x)
            where x <= case when @InsertType = 'Single' then 1 else 5 end


    IF @LineAssoc = 'None'
        INSERT INTO BudDat(PropertyID, 
            PropertyNumber, 
            GLAccountNumber, 
            DeptCode, 
            [Year], 
            BudgetID, 
            Comments, 
            LastChangedDate, 
            LastChangedBy) 
            SELECT @PropertyID, 
            @PropertyNumber, 
            @GLAccountNumber, 
            @DeptCode,
            @ClickYear, 
            '', 
            @Comments, 
            getDate(), 
            @User
            from (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) as Numbers(x)
            where x <= case when @InsertType = 'Multiple' then 1 else 5 end
```

btw...not really sure why this is tagged as sql-server. It seems as though the procedure itself is fine. Obviously the issue is somewhere in your php.

Comment: Yes, this is a php issue but trying to run the SQL stored procedure.  My issue is why it doesn't run through PHP?